# php file_get_contents(). How to retrieve particular div tags from body via url

Tags: php, url, curl, file-get-contents

How do i retrieve a specific div tag class/id from a page url.

i use the first function to get the title.
the second for the div class is giving me a problem.
 Here is the code i used .

```
    function website_title() {
   $ch = curl_init();
   $url=$_POST['urle'];
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   // some websites like Facebook need a user agent to be set.
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.94 Safari/537.36');
   $html = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);

   $dom  = new DOMDocument;
   @$dom->loadHTML($html);

   $title = $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')->item('0')->nodeValue;
   echo $title;
}
function website_content() {
  // $ch = curl_init();
   $url=$_POST['urle'];
  //$html = file_get_contents($url);
$html = file_get_contents(url);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); //Prevents Warnings, remove if desired
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use getElementsByTagName, get all divs and check for class. Better and easier way is to use some library, that will make it easier for you, i.e. SimpleDomParser:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I highly endorse this approach. The built-in PHP classes for parsing HTML don't come with an HTML cleaner for when you're faced with code which works in your browser but won't parse properly by PHP. The simplehtmldom library has worked wonders for me in several complicated projects of the past, when other methods were encountering issues when trying to parse it as XML due to its strictness. You can rely on this library, it's never failed me, not even with large data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DomXPath for getting tags with specified class. For example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($DOM);
$myClassName = $finder->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@itemprop), ' '), ' myClassName ')]");
```

Then you can iterate `$myClassName` like dom node list.

Answer (score 0):

I use DOMXPath to sort out specific elements, like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML( $html );
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
```

To get all divs, I would use:

```
$divs = $xpath->query( '//div' );
```

To get all divs with class "className" I use:

```
$divs = $xpath->query( '//div[@class="className"]' );
```

To get contents of the first find, use it this way:

```
$content = $divs->item( 0 )->nodeValue;
```